# Create array of worksheets not variant

Tags: arrays, excel, vba

I would like to create an array of type worksheet, not variant, then populate the array using the Array function and finally pass the array to the worksheet.copy function to crate a new workbook of the worksheets in the array variables.

The following code works but none of the arrays are of type worksheet and two of the example arrays are populated with the worksheet names.

```
Dim wbkThis         As Workbook
Dim wstX            As Worksheet
Dim wstY            As Worksheet
Dim wstZ            As Worksheet
Dim arrWSA          As Variant
Dim arrWSB()        As Variant
Dim arrWSC(1 To 3)  As Variant

Cancel = True

Set wbkThis = ThisWorkbook
Set wstX = wbkThis.Worksheets("SheetX")
Set wstY = wbkThis.Worksheets("SheetY")
Set wstZ = wbkThis.Worksheets("SheetZ")
ReDim arrWSA(1 To 3) As Variant
ReDim arrWSB(1 To 3) As Variant

arrWSA = Array(wstX, wstY, wstZ)
arrWSB = Array(wstX.Name, wstY.Name, wstZ.Name)
arrWSC(1) = wstX.Name
arrWSC(2) = wstY.Name
arrWSC(3) = wstZ.Name

arrWSA(1).Copy
Worksheets(arrWSB()).Copy
Worksheets(arrWSC()).Copy
```

Comment: `Worksheets` is already a collection of sheets, why not use that?

Answer (score 0):

While you can create an array of worksheets, it won't work to copy them all at once (though you could copy them in a loop). An array of names is the way to go if you want to copy multiple sheets at once.

```vb
Sub CopySheets()
    Dim shtCount As Long: shtCount = Worksheets.Count
    Dim X As Long

    Dim arrSheets() As Worksheet: ReDim arrSheets(1 To shtCount)

    For X = LBound(arrSheets) To UBound(arrSheets)
        Set arrSheets(X) = Worksheets(X)
    Next X

'    Worksheets(arrSheets).Copy After:=Worksheets(shtCount) 'This won't work.

    For X = LBound(arrSheets) To UBound(arrSheets)
        arrSheets(X).Copy After:=Worksheets(shtCount) 'this will
    Next X


    Dim arrShtNames() As String: ReDim arrShtNames(1 To shtCount)
    For X = LBound(arrShtNames) To UBound(arrShtNames)
        arrShtNames(X) = Worksheets(X).Name
    Next X

    Worksheets(arrShtNames).Copy After:=Worksheets(shtCount) 'this will as well

End Sub
```